# cwrsync --link-dest not working

Tags: rsync

all.
I use Cwrsync on my Windows machine to transfer a folder to a Linux machine.In order to reduse disk usage, I use `--link-dest` parm. It works fine on my machine, but `--link-dest` is not working on another Windows machine.Confusing!

Here is my rsync command:

```
rsync -rvzR  --link-dest=bak/001 /cygdrive/e/tmp/ root@192.168.3.1:bak/002
```

Comment: "Not working" how?

Comment: Hi,ams. I use du -sh on dest machine, but I get the same size when I use link-dest

Comment: That's expected; `--link-dest` uses hard links so they look like real files to `du`. However, I'm not sure if the Windows filesystem supports that feature anyway?